# Any way to implement implicit "it" in Ruby blocks, like in Lisp?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Apparently in Lisp when you write a block/lambda without parameters, the word "it" takes the value passed in to the block.

This seems elegant; I like it; I want it in Ruby. Is there any way to make it work?

```
3.times { p it }
```

should print "0 1 2"

Obviously I could eval a block in a context that included a method_missing that returned a value for :it (or maybe def Object#it). But what value should it return? If I "yield 42" to a block, and the block was declared without parameters, is there any general way to recover the value 42?

(The original version of this question asked about C#, hence the comments. Apparently C# doesn't have this but Lisp does.)

Comment: Could you give a C# example illustrating that? It's the first time I heard of it, and it seems so different from the test of the language.

Comment: Perhaps you are confused with something related to lambda? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx FYI, Lisp **does** have such a construct and the community call it "anaphoric macro" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro

Comment: You could try to work around it but I don't think you'd get it to work. Even if you did, you'd end up creating a change in Ruby's behavior that would make your code unlike all other Ruby code, becoming a maintenance issue. It's better to accept that one language is different than another, and learn to work with their built-in syntax.

Comment: It wasn't C#, it was Lisp. My bad. Thanks, nodakai. The question about how to put something like it into Ruby remains...